# System-wide gesture recognition on iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, jailbreak, uiwindow

How can I detect system-wide gestures on iOS like the built in iOS multitasking gestures or like Zephyr?  Using Logos, what should I hook to be able to use touchesBegan, touchesMoved, etc.?

I'm hoping to be able to implement a three-finger swipe up/down that's recognized from pretty much anywhere except the lockscreen.

(Please don't answer telling me to just use Activator).

**EDIT: by hook I mean something like "%hook UIApplication." Just clarifying because there seemed to be confusion when I've asked others.**

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered examining the source code for Activator? Surely that will point you in the right direction. It's available [here](https://github.com/rpetrich/libactivator).